# Better sorting technique for almost sorted list

Tags: sorting

Which is the best sorting technique for an almost sorted list and why? For a list of many elements I found that quick sort is helpful.But which sort have a better running time when it is already sorted?

Comment: This is a theoretical CS question, but it isn't mathematically precise, so it can't be easily answered. Can you please define exactly what you mean be "almost sorted?" For example, is an "almost sorted" list one where two elements are swapped, but the rest are in order? Is it one in which 90% or more of the elements do not need to be moved to finish sorting the list?

Comment: I am sorry that i haven't explained the question exactly. I am talking about the list which is almost like 95% of the elements do not need to be moved for sorting. @Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion Sort has linear performance when list is almost sorted.

Check : http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/nearly-sorted-initial-order

Insertion places an element at correct position considering the relative ordering hence need n - 1 iterations. Other sorts like quick sort again tries to sort a sorted segment again as it is unaware of relative ordering (ie if segment is already sorted).

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is too broad , however If the input array is already sorted, insertion sort performs as few as n-1 comparisons thats make insertion sort more efficient

you may find this paper helpful 
[Best sorting algorithm for nearly sorted lists](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=359024.359026)